# What are the rules for combining/reducing quantifiers?

Tags: logic

Suppose $\forall x P(x)$.

Suppose $\forall y Q(y)$.

Intuitively, I would say therefore $(\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.  However I want to derive this step-by-step:

Then $(\forall x P(x)) \land (\forall y Q(y))$ by conjunctive introduction.

Then $(\forall x \forall y (P(x) \land Q(y))$ by ???. What rule is this called?

Then $(\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ by ???. Is this a valid step to take? If so what rule is this called?

In general, what are the rules for combining/reducing quantifiers?

Comment: NO. First $\forall$-elimination, to get $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$. Then $\land$-intro followed by $\forall$-intro.

Comment: And we need to know the domain of $x$ and the domain of $y$.  If the domain of $x$ is all human beings, and the domain of y is all elements on the periodic chart in chemistry, we need to keep those domains separate.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why not put this together into an answer? (Though, I would say that natural deduction is just one presentation of the rules of classical first-order logic, and that different presentations will have different things that they consider "steps" and thus different "step-by-step" proofs.)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thanks for the reply! If I used $\forall$-elimination on $\forall x P(x)$ to get $P(a)$, wouldn't have I have to "remember" that $a$ came from $\forall$ so that it's valid to use $\forall$-intro?  If so, where is that notated/stored?  Otherwise if I had $\exists z R(z)$ and used $\exists$-elimination to get $R(c)$ I might erroneously use $\forall$-intro on $R(c)$.

Comment: Incidentally, thinking about your recent questions note that Mauro's answer involves exactly a multiple-hypothesis deduction ("From $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$, we apply $\wedge$-introduction") whereas the approach you outline doesn't. In general, systems allowing multiple-hypothesis deductions are really the right way to go, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: "recent questions" Recent questions the complexity classes to decide various grammars?

Comment: @Noah Schweber: "whereas the approach you outline doesn't" I wondered if I could eliminate quantifier elimiation

Comment: @Noah Schweber: "really the right way to go, for a variety of reasons" why?

Answer (score 2):

From $\forall x P(x)$, by $∀$-elimination, we derive $P(a)$ and the same with $\forall x Q(x)$.

Now, from $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$, we apply $\land$-introduction to get: $P(a) \land Q(a)$.

Finally, we apply $\forall$-introduction to get:

> $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.

---

Regarding the [Natural Deduction rules for quantifiers](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7): $\forall$-elim and $\exists$-intro have no restrictions.

The restrictions regarding quantifying variable that bare *free* in open assumptions affect $\forall$-intro and $\exists$-elim.

Specifically, if we have $\exists z R(z)$ and we assume $R(c)$ for $\exists$-elim, the above restriction prevents us from using $\forall$-intro to derive invalidly $\forall x R(x)$.